# K3s LAN test with Nginx Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, curl, nginx-ingress, k3s

I have a local bare metal server in my LAN together with my laptop. I'm using K3s in the server where I have installed the k3s without Traefik to use then Nginx Ingress.

Insalling K3s without Traefik `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -s - --disable=traefik`

I have installed Nginx Ingress with:
`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.4.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml`

Then I'm using the following example:

```
---
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: apple-app
  labels:
    app: apple
spec:
  containers:
    - name: apple-app
      image: hashicorp/http-echo
      args:
        - "-text=apple"
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: apple-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: apple
  ports:
    - port: 5678 # Default port for image
---
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: banana-app
  labels:
    app: banana
spec:
  containers:
    - name: banana-app
      image: hashicorp/http-echo
      args:
        - "-text=banana"
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: banana-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: banana
  ports:
    - port: 5678 # Default port for image
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /apple
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: apple-service
              port:
                number: 5678
        - path: /banana
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: banana-service
              port:
                number: 5678
```

What I want to achieve is to connect from my laptop to the k3s server cluster, but I don't have connectivity. I write here the descriptions and connections I try:

sudo kubectl get all -A

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                                READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system     pod/local-path-provisioner-5b5579c644-2th9x         1/1     Running     0          10h
kube-system     pod/coredns-75fc8f8fff-hssqn                        1/1     Running     0          10h
kube-system     pod/metrics-server-5c8978b444-m6pdb                 1/1     Running     0          10h
kube-system     pod/svclb-ingress-nginx-controller-369211b6-dvtz8   2/2     Running     0          2m13s
ingress-nginx   pod/ingress-nginx-admission-create-n78x2            0/1     Completed   0          2m13s
ingress-nginx   pod/ingress-nginx-admission-patch-9gwfj             0/1     Completed   1          2m13s
ingress-nginx   pod/ingress-nginx-controller-7844b9db77-8vhzr       1/1     Running     0          2m13s
default         pod/apple-app                                       1/1     Running     0          71s
default         pod/banana-app                                      1/1     Running     0          71s

NAMESPACE       NAME                                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
default         service/kubernetes                           ClusterIP      10.43.0.1       <none>          443/TCP                      10h
kube-system     service/kube-dns                             ClusterIP      10.43.0.10      <none>          53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       10h
kube-system     service/metrics-server                       ClusterIP      10.43.36.133    <none>          443/TCP                      10h
ingress-nginx   service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.43.179.190   <none>          443/TCP                      2m13s
ingress-nginx   service/ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.43.134.133   192.168.1.195   80:31304/TCP,443:30428/TCP   2m13s
default         service/apple-service                        ClusterIP      10.43.29.31     <none>          5678/TCP                     71s
default         service/banana-service                       ClusterIP      10.43.146.142   <none>          5678/TCP                     71s

NAMESPACE     NAME                                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/svclb-ingress-nginx-controller-369211b6   1         1         1       1            1           <none>          2m13s

NAMESPACE       NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system     deployment.apps/local-path-provisioner     1/1     1            1           10h
kube-system     deployment.apps/coredns                    1/1     1            1           10h
kube-system     deployment.apps/metrics-server             1/1     1            1           10h
ingress-nginx   deployment.apps/ingress-nginx-controller   1/1     1            1           2m13s

NAMESPACE       NAME                                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
kube-system     replicaset.apps/local-path-provisioner-5b5579c644     1         1         1       10h
kube-system     replicaset.apps/coredns-75fc8f8fff                    1         1         1       10h
kube-system     replicaset.apps/metrics-server-5c8978b444             1         1         1       10h
ingress-nginx   replicaset.apps/ingress-nginx-controller-7844b9db77   1         1         1       2m13s

NAMESPACE       NAME                                       COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
ingress-nginx   job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-create   1/1           13s        2m13s
ingress-nginx   job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-patch    1/1           14s        2m13s
```

sudo kubectl describe ingress -A

```
Name:             demo-localhost
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        default
Address:          192.168.1.195
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host              Path  Backends
  ----              ----  --------
  demo.localdev.me  
                    /   demo:80 (<error: endpoints "demo" not found>)
Annotations:        <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    112s  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync


Name:             example-ingress
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        default
Address:          192.168.1.195
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /apple    apple-service:5678 (10.42.0.21:5678)
              /banana   banana-service:5678 (10.42.0.22:5678)
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    52s (x2 over 84s)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

connections from the same server:

```
curl http://10.43.29.31:5678
apple

curl http://10.43.146.142:5678
banana

curl  http://192.168.1.195/banana
<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

curl  -v http://10.43.134.133:31304/banana
*   Trying 10.43.134.133:31304...

curl   http://10.43.134.133:80/banana
<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

curl -v http://localhost/banana
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
*   Trying ::1:80...
* connect to ::1 port 80 failed: Connection refused

 curl -v http://localhost:31304/banana
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:31304...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 31304 (#0)
> GET /banana HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:31304
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Time-out
< Date: Sat, 12 Nov 2022 07:50:36 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 160
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

connections from my laptop:

```
curl 192.168.1.195/apple              
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.195 port 80 after 25912 ms: Operation timed out

curl 192.168.1.195:31304/banana
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.195 port 31304 after 25910 ms: Operation timed out
```

Anybody can tell me what I'm missing in this deployment? why is not even possible to connect to localhost from the server itself.

### thanks,
David

Checking the connectivity reveals I can access the server from the laptop but the port from NodePort is not reacting to petitions:

from the laptop:

```
traceroute 192.168.1.195  
traceroute to 192.168.1.195 (192.168.1.195), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.195 (192.168.1.195)  9.376 ms  8.858 ms  2.318 ms

ping 192.168.1.195
PING 192.168.1.195 (192.168.1.195): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.195: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=3.963 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.195: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.332 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.195 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss

telnet 192.168.1.195 31304
Trying 192.168.1.195...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.195: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

from the server:

```
telnet fanless 31304
Trying 127.0.1.1...
Connected to fanless.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.

telnet localhost 31304
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.

telnet 192.168.1.195 31304
Trying 192.168.1.195...
Connected to 192.168.1.195.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.

telnet 192.168.1.195 80
Trying 192.168.1.195...
Connected to 192.168.1.195.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.
```

checking ufw and iptables:

```
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive

sudo service iptables status
Unit iptables.service could not be found.
```

checking the ports of the machine that are in listening status. The external port of the LoadBalancer of the Ingres doesn't appear...

```
netstat -nlupt
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      160578/python3      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10010         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:42149         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      160622/python       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10249         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10248         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10257         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10256         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10259         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10258         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54075         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      160622/python       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6444          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40523         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      160814/python       
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:41489         :::*                    LISTEN      160577/java         
tcp6       0      0 :::6443                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::32075                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:35573         :::*                    LISTEN      160577/java         
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:4040          :::*                    LISTEN      160577/java         
tcp6       0      0 :::2222                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:39363         :::*                    LISTEN      160577/java         
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 192.168.1.195:68        0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8472            0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

If I check the k3s nodes, the node doesn't have an external IP, would this be the problem?

```
sudo kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME      STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION        INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
fanless   Ready    control-plane,master   17h   v1.25.3+k3s1   192.168.1.195   <none>        Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS   5.15.0-52-generic   containerd://1.6.8-k3s1`
```

---

Running in Docker Desktop with an additional service in "/" path

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: peach-service
              port:
                number: 5678
        - path: /apple
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: apple-service
              port:
                number: 5678
        - path: /banana
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: banana-service
              port:
                number: 5678
```

```
curl localhost/apple
apple

curl localhost/peach
peach

curl localhost/banana
banana
```

Comment: Connections to localhost:31304 do work: nginx returns 504, something wrong with ingress configuration, not able to route your request properly? localhost on port 80 won't work, this is expected. And connections from your laptop are most likely blocked if you did not expose your nodePorts ports, starting k3s.

Comment: if I try the same configuration in the laptop with Docker desktop it is working. So, I guess the ingress is OK. Why it's not working with localhost? on Docker desktop instead of the 192.168.1.195 I have localhost for the ingress. Then, how to expose the nodePorts when starting k3s? thanks

Comment: localhost:80 not working => the nodePort is exposed on port 31304. I'm not sure how come 192.168.1.195:80 does work, but that's not part of the configuration you shared with us. Connections from your laptop: check for routing (does traffic reach 192.168.1.195, use tcpdump, maybe you're missing a route, otherwise there's some firewall blocking that traffic in, and not sending any response in return). you start k3s as a container? which options do you use? do you expose ports? (docker "-p" options). Probably should add whichever nodePorts you want to use, check for ip forwarding, iptables rules

Comment: I've added more info about the connectivity. I can reach the server from the laptop. Doing telnet from the server works whereas it's not working from the laptop. If I do a netstat I don't see the external port of the nodeport of the ingress in listening status. I guess it's something related to how the ingress/load balancer is tied to the server but I don't know what is wrong there. Do you know if I'm missing something given the fact that it's a bare metal server in this case?

Comment: how do you start k3s?

Comment: it starts alone after installing it. I have tried reinstalling with:  ```curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -s - --disable=traefik --node-external-ip=192.168.1.195```
but I still have the http petitions working

Comment: Hi, I adapted my case from this tutorial and got it working: https://moonstreet.nl/post/k3s-with-ingress/